# Connecting Azure VM to Redshift DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, connection, amazon-redshift

I'm running an analytical application on an Azure VM and need to connect to a Redshift database.

Both of these softwares have complex company security policies that I've tried to unravel. All necessary ports are open, accepting incoming and outgoing. But when I try to connect to Redshift using the ODBC Administrator on the Azure, I get this error:

```
[Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (10) Error occurred while trying to connect: [SQLState HY000] fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I have supplied a password to the ODBC connection, why is this happening?

Also, when clearing IP addresses to connect to the Azure, which IP do I use for the Redshift? All the IPs associated with the compute nodes, or the IP that comes back when I check the IP address of the Redshift endpoint?

Thanks!

Comment: For the second part of your question, you connect to Redshift using the DNS endpoint and not the IP address.

Comment: Yes, but I have to figure out how to clear that endpoint through my security. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: When you say "your security" can you clarify? Modern enterprise firewalls support DNS endpoints. I would open a new question if this is now a firewall question. Include make and model.